# Node-red crash / JSON output sometimes returns html

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

My node-red is crashing multiple times per day.
One of the problems I think that may be the cause is an http request I am doing.

I am requesting the output of a webpage in JSON.
But sometimes I see in the log that returns an error in HTML.
There is probably something wrong on the webpage serverside, but my flow is erroring out on this.

```
SyntaxError: undefined:1 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> ^ Unexpected token <

2 Jan 15:26:26 - [error] [function:Filter temperatures] SyntaxError: undefined:1
```

Can I edit my functions to be able to filter this out, and hopefully not crash node-red any more?

This is an example of a function I am using to parse the JSON.

```
datarequest = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
msg1 = {};
msg1.payload = datarequest.data.valvesetat.bypass;


return [msg1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the web page is returning something that is not JSON (some kind of error, I guess) and the `JSON.parse()` fails to parse it.

Enclose the `JSON.parse()` part in a `try/catch` block and manage the response of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no `{` characters in the HTML around the JSON, you could try:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.replace(/^.*?(\{/{.*\}).*/, '$1');
```

before calling `JSON.parse`.

Comment: there are { characters around the JSON.
99% of the time it works fine. It's just that sometimes it errors out and that's when the problems begin.

Comment: I mean when it sends the extra HTML, are there any `{` in the HTML part?

Comment: That will prevent this solution from working, because it assumes that the JSON starts at the first `{` and ends with the last `}`. If that's not the case, you'll need to use a different regular expression that matches what you're actually getting.